# flex 4.6 pom file dependency is not resolving

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash-builder, pom.xml, flex4.6

I am trying to convert flex 4.6 project into maven Following is my pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-RC2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0.23201</version>
                <type>pom</type>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>wrapper</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <parameters>
                    <swf>${build.finalName}</swf>
                    <width>100%</width>
                    <height>100%</height>
                  </parameters>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
          <version>4.6.0.23201</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>flexmojos</id>
      <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Error I am getting is as follows:

> [ERROR]   The project com.adobe:gDash-main-maven:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   (C:\\pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR]     Unresolveable build
>   extension: Plugin com.adobe.flex.compiler:batik- all-flex:4.6.0.23201
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.adobe.flex.compiler:batik-all-flex:jar :4.6.0.23201,
>   com.adobe.flex:compiler:pom:4.6.0.23201: Could not find artifact com.adobe.flex.compiler:batik-all-flex:jar:4.6.0.23201 in central
>   (http://repo.ma ven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 2]
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin
>   com.adobe.flex.compile r:batik-all-flex:4.6.0.23201 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: T he following artifacts could not
>   be resolved: com.adobe.flex.compiler:batik-all- flex:jar:4.6.0.23201,
>   com.adobe.flex:compiler:pom:4.6.0.23201: Could not find ar tifact
>   com.adobe.flex.compiler:batik-all-flex:jar:4.6.0.23201 in central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem. Add this to your `pom.xml` file (after `<repositories>...</repositories>` for instance):

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>flex-mojos-plugin-repository</id>
       <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Solved it for me :)

Some IDEs will generate a POM file already containing this plugin repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the repo, you see that

http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/com/adobe/flex/framework/flex-framework/

does not exist for version 4.6.0.23201, but for version 4.6.b.23201 instead

Comment: I have changed and tried still the same error. I suppose to use a different version of flexmojos?

Comment: I changed that.. But I am getting FATAL ERROR. Because of the character 'b' in version. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b". I am using maven 2.2.1

Comment: Its fixed.. Its because of flexmojos version. Earlier I was used 3.6.1. Now I changed to 3.8.. After that everything is working fine with maven 2.2.1..